# Data deleted from DB successfully but not refreshed the current page in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I tried several times to delete data and it successfully delete data but not show updated the student full list.....

After manually refresh the web page then it shows the updated student list please help me.

```html
  
X.controller('StudentController', ['$scope', 'Student', 'Department', '$routeParams','$location', function ($scope, Student, Department, $routeParams,$location) {
    $scope.v = 'test value';
    
    $scope.profileid = $routeParams.Id;
    console.log($scope.profileid);
        ////////////////RETRIVE ALL DATA FROM DB///////////////
    function init() {
        /////RETRIVE DATA FOR STUDENT/////////
   
        $scope.student = { Name: '', Phone: '', Class_id: '', Department_id: '' };
        $scope.students = [];
        Student.get(function (response) {
            console.log("List of Student");
            $scope.students = response.Data;
            console.log($scope.students);

        });

        ///////RETRIVE DATA FOR DEPARTMENT////////////////////
        $scope.depts = [];
        Department.get(function (response) {
            console.log("List of Dept");
            $scope.depts = response.DeptData;
            console.log($scope.depts);
        });

    };
////////////RETRIVE SPECIFIC DATA INTO DB/////////////
Student.get({ Id: $scope.profileid }, function (response) {
        console.log("SPECIFIC DATA");
        $scope.student = response.Data;
        console.log($scope.students);

    });
/////////////////////////////DELETE//////////////////
    $scope.Stddelete = function (profileId) {
        Student.delete({ Id: profileId });
        console.log("DELETE");
        init();
    };

    init();



    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

To update the DOM, you need to `splice` the object from the array.

```
$scope.students.splice($index,1);
```

Example:

```
$scope.Stddelete = function (profileId,index) {
        Student.delete({ Id: profileId });
        $scope.students.splice(index,1);
        console.log("DELETE");
        init();
    };
```